# Get centroids from white ROIs - Opencv (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I'd want to get the centroids of several white regions and I'm trying with findContours(), then getting the moments and calculating the centroids. However, I'm not sure what it is stored in contours and how to do it well...

This is the code

```
# load the image
image = cv2.imread('mask.png',0) # Black and white image

 contours, _, _ = cv2.findContours(image,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Why only a row??
cnt = contours[1]

M = cv2.moments(cnt)
print M

cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

print contours
```

Any help would be appreciate! :)

Answer (score 0):

[`cv2.findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) detects contours, where each contour is stored as a vector of points - in your case it is a Python list of all the contours in the image. Each individual contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of boundary points of the object.

Comment: First, sorry for the delay. Right now, as I have the code, contours have the same size as the image (480x640) and if I show it as an image, contours can be seen. However, if I want to get the centroids I don't know how to do it from then.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a binary image named *rmask*, then I have done the following in python:

```
cv2.imshow('Red mask',rmask)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(rmask.copy(), 1, 2)
# image stores the image of contours, contours store an array containing all the boundary points of an object
moments = [cv2.moments(cnt) for cnt in contours]
centroids = [(int(M['m10'] / M['m00']), int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])) for M in moments]
for c in centroids:
    cv2.circle(rmask, c, 5, (0, 0, 0))
cv2.imshow('img', rmask)
```

The above code worked for me.